# "-phile" word for someone who loves frogs

Tags: single-word-requests, morphology, greek

What would the best word be to describe a frog-lover that ends with the *-phile* root?

Comment: I really want to know some context for this question. Why would you ever need a word for someone who loves frogs?

Comment: @Seamus: I have a friend who loves frogs... I wanted to know what to call them =P.

Comment: I think the official term is francophile :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The word for the fear of frogs is [*batrachophobia*](http://www.phobia-fear-release.com/batrachophobia.html), although Wikipedia suggests it is [*ranidaphobia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_frogs).  However, the suffix *-phile* is Greek, and there is a "rule" that the components for such a word should all be from the same root language, rather than mixing root languages.  (This is really more of a common style choice and not a grammatical requirement.)  The Classical Greek word for frog is [*batrachos*](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2354) (and *rana* is Latin).  So, following that logic, the Greek word for frog should be used (rather than Latin or anything else).

So, I think the purist answer for someone who loves frogs would be ***batrachophile***.

The don't-care-about-mixing-Latin-and-Greek answer would be ***ranidaphile*** (with the advantage that this connects with *ranidae*, the scientific term for the most common frog family).

The who-cares-about-disguising-English-with-smart-sounding-words-from-dead-languages answer is ***frogophile***.

Comment: heh, I looked around a bit and found batracophile myself, but frogophile never crossed my mind =P

Comment: You have somehow managed to combine an eloquent and well-referenced answer with a humorous and well-aimed joke. I would +2 if I could!

Comment: There's a perfect Miss Piggy reference in here somewhere, but I just can't force it to stick its ample pink nose out where I can see it. ;-)

Comment: +1 for *batrachophile*, but +gazillion for *frogophile*. I think it's safe to say that *-phile* is now as much an English (German, Spanish, Russian, French,...) morpheme as it is a Greek one. The equivalent of *frogophile* would work in pretty much every language I am familiar with. Of course, it has a jokey connotation, but a) so does *frog lover*, and b) there are probably not extremely many people on this planet who would understand *batrachophile* at all. In short, one is a better fit for scientific contexts, while the other is best suited for everyday conversation.

Comment: Frogophile if the first thing that came to my mind, but I can't help wondering if it's actually frogs or just the fricasseed legs that are of interest.

Comment: @RegDwight: good point.. frogophile is probably the way to go. although interestingly the first google hit points to [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=frogophile) which uses it as a disparaging term for nationalistic French people..

Comment: @Claudiu: hehe, ah yes, the Urban Dictionary... They are like that. Anyhow, looking at their own stats (6 upvotes, 4 downvotes) I don't think this term is popular at all, and it's certainly not anywhere as derogatory as [certain others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese-eating_surrender_monkeys). Personally, I would use *frogophile* without fear (and to support that claim, I am bravely posting this from a PC in sight of the French border).

Comment: @RegDwight: Not only is the *-phile* suffix an English suffix now, but it has also evolved a different, narrower meaning than the original Greek suffix ever had.