# Why do some words containing a form of “philia” have it at the beginning and some have it at the end?

Tags: suffixes, prefixes, morphology, derivational-morphology, greek

There are words like “philosophy”, “philology”, “philanthropy”; these have a form of “philia” at the beginning. Why don't these words have it at the end?

Also, there are words like “haemophilia”, “hydrophilia”, “paedophilia”; these have a form of “philia” at the end. Why don't these words have it at the beginning?

Why don't all words with a form of “philia” have it on the same side? What is the rule for deciding if it goes to the beginning or the end of the word?

Comment: Why do you suppose the _philia_ root should always go at the same end? There are also words with _anthropos_ at both ends: _philanthrophy_ and _anthropology_; or _logos_ at both ends: _logophilia_ and _philology_. And so on. These are all Greek roots and they went together centuries (in some cases millennia) ago, long before there was English or printing or spelling. Questions that ask ***Why*** something in language is the way it is never have satisfying answers -- the answer is always "That's just the way it fell out."

Comment: related: [frogophile](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3999/phile-word-for-someone-who-loves-frogs) (has a good answer and relevante commentary about "-phile" suffix)

Comment: I think that a form of “philia” should always go to the same end in these cases because of consistency. In all words which I used as examples in the question, the relation is the same. It's a feeling (love) towards its object (wisdom, words, people, blood, water, children). The relations between the things described by the parts of the words “philanthropy” and “anthropology” are different. “Philanthropy” means love for people, and “anthropology” means words about (studying of) people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a Greek native speaker. I did some research and I found some info in Greek that I believe will help as the words you mention are Greek. So

**philo-word**

- 1a. in compound adjectives, identifies one who is characterized by love or a favourable attitude towards what the second compound expresses: philanthropist
- b. characterizes the corresponding attitude or behavior(the example in Greek is liberalism but I can't think of something to explain it better.)
- states that the determined behaviour or in general the tactics or politics of an individual or a group is characterized by a friendly attitude towards the people that expresses the second compound;
  e.g. philhellene

Now **word-philo**

- b 'synthetic in compound names. 1. identifies the one who loves what the first synthetic expresses: a. (often science) for plants that thrive in the environment that implies the first synthetic(e.g. hydrophilic)
- the person characterized by the pathological condition implied by the corresponding noun e.g. haemophilia
- indicates the person who is characterized by a friendly attitude towards the people that expresses the first synthetic;  anglophile also   hydrophile, bibliophile

***highly IMPORTANT***  you should know that the philo-word declares the healthy love for something and

the word-philo means too much love for something.(MOSTLY NOT IN A GOOD WAY such as paedophilia.)

I will provide some links in Greek (I apologize for that) in case you want something more. I hope I have shed some light.

- philo-word https://www.greek-language.gr/greekLang/modern_greek/tools/lexica/triantafyllides/search.html?lq=%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BB%CE%BF*&dq=
- word-philo https://www.greek-language.gr/greekLang/modern_greek/tools/lexica/triantafyllides/search.html?start=0&lq=*%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BB%CE%BF&dq=
- more infohttps://www.translatum.gr/forum/index.php?topic=14297.0
  Edits: Added more info and examples.

Comment: I'm not convinced that X-phile words tend to have pejorative connotations. Being an audiophile or a cinephile or bibliophile aren't inherently bad things. I can't think of any others that are.

Comment: Of course not always but in some cases it happens.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Of course not always but in some cases it happens. At least in Greek. e.g. necrophiliac. In Greek Wikipedia<https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82> it states "which is in a pathological state or is dependent on what the first synthetic indicates". This is one of many possible explanations. I just thought that I should point this out.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie It's not universal, but the over-much usage for *-philia* (but not *-phile* or *philo-*) is pretty interesting. I could see an answer delving more into the *diagnostic* history of *-philia* to discuss that usage, whereas *philo-* and *-phile* don't have that history.